# The application crashes on a StackOverflow error

Tags: java, spring, websphere, activiti

The application crashes from time to time on a StackOverflow error with the *stacktrace see below*.

The error occurs unexpectedly in various scenarios. We are not able to simulate it or predict its occurrence.

Is there any workaround for this bug in version 5?
Or maybe there is a chance that this error can be solved by upgrading framework activiti version 5 to framework activiti 6?

Thank you in advance.

Full stacktrace you can find here: https://pastebin.com/9niRtryH

**Stacktrace errors (shortened version):**

```
ErrorController.error(29) - ErrorController with status:500 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) ~[javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:?] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) ~[javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at cz.binta.kasanova.filters.HtmlEscapelFilter.doFilter(HtmlEscapelFilter.java:23) ~[classes/:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at cz.binta.kasanova.filters.BranchThreadLocalFilter.doFilterInternal(BranchThreadLocalFilter.java:33) ~[classes/:?] 

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at cz.binta.kasanova.filters.LoggingMDCFilter.doFilter(LoggingMDCFilter.java:38) ~[classes/:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?] 

at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558) [?:CCX.CF [o1800.01]] 

at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608) [?:CCX.CF [o1800.01]] 

at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985) [?:CCX.CF [o1800.01]] 

at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074) [?:CCX.CF [o1800.01]] 

at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?] 

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError 

at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0] 

at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:643) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0] 

at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0] 

at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0] 

at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0] 

at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0] 
...........................
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE] 

... 41 more
```

Comment: A StackOverFlow error occurs when your program runs out of memory, that means that your code is using most probably keeping a large amount of data in memory without being able to free it. To find the root of your problem I would need to know all the logic that your controller is doing and also your server specs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your
`org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync` and
`org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation` methods are getting called recursively hundreds of times which causes your stack to overflow, fix them.